# Unable to resize a partition on my debian

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

I added an extra 10GB to a vmware virtualized Debian 10

Actual situation is 
[image]

Another point of view

[image]

Result of `fdisk -l`

[image]
I need to make larger the /dev/sda5 partition.

I tried using

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5
```

[image]

But I obtained no changes.

I found various stackexchange answers, but all of them ended using or graphical tools (I cannot, it's a command line only environment) or the already tried `resize2fs` command

So, short version: *How can I make larger the /dev/sda5 partition?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Googling, I ended up rebooting VM using GParted Live Cd and all was easily done.

Answer (score 0):

I may be incorrect but I don't think you can just add space to `sda5` unless it is part of a volume group - have a look at `lvm`.

You have effectively added space to the *end* of the drive so it could probably be added to `sda8` since that is the last sequential partition.

It may be useful to have a look at the output of `lsblk` - on one of my servers for example:

```
lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                     2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda                     8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                  8:5    0 19.1G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0 15.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                     8:16   0  500G  0 disk 
└─data-data           252:2    0  500G  0 lvm  /data
```

In my case if I expanded `sdb` I would then use

```
# For info - ensure /dev/sdb shows the new size
fdisk -l /dev/sdb

# resize a disk or partition in use by LVM2
pvresize /dev/sdb

# For info - the field "Free PE" should show the newly added space
#  Free  PE / Size       12800 / 50.00 GiB
vgdisplay data

# Extend the logical volume to use the free space
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/data/data
```